# Ошибка: не удается преобразовать из "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>" в "string"

Tags: c#, wpf

```
[DataContract]
internal class Notice
{
    [DataMember]
    public ProductSale[] data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
internal class Answer
{
    [DataMember]
    public Notice notice { get; set; }
}
private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async Task<string> GetStringАsync(string url)
{
    var basic = Convert.ToBase64String(
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ipopov:211103"));

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basic);
     var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

public  IEnumerable<ProductSale> GetProductSale()
{
    var json = GetStringАsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProductSale");
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var answer = serializer.Deserialize<Answer>(json);
    return  answer.notice.data.ToList();
}
```

Я написал асинхронный запрос и у меня есть ошибка

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>" в "string".
```

Видимо связано с этим

```
var answer = serializer.Deserialize<Answer>(json);
```

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку и проверить код, Спасибо

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

У вас кроме всего прочего ещё и название функции `GetStringАsync` везде написано русской буквой `А` в слове `Async`.
Так то первым делом нужно все функции, где есть в названии `Async`, вызывать с помощью `await`, но из-за путаницы с буквой простой поиск по коду слова `Async`, чтобы проверить, правильно ли все асинхронные функции вызываются в коде через `await`, не даёт найти в вашем коде строку с вызовом этой функции.

Comment: СПАСИБО ПОМЕНЯЛ