# Реализация метода, асинхронный запрос

Tags: c#, wpf

Я написал метод:

```
public async Task<ProductSale[]> GetProductSaleAsync()
        {
            var json = await GetStringАsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProductSale");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(json).notice.data;
        }
```

и у меня ошибка:

> "MySQLDataProvider" не реализует член интерфейса "IDataProvider.GetProductSale()"

если я нажимаю реализовать интерфейс, он реализуется вот так:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductSale> GetProductSale()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Как мне изменить код, чтобы видел его `MySQLDataProvider`?

Comment: Так реализуйте тело метода таким образом, каким вы хотите его видеть. C# просто просит Вас реализовать то, на что подписались (на интерфейс). Интерфейс это просто контракт, если не хотите реализовывать то, что требуется - оставьте `throw new NotImplementedException` или измените на `throw new NotSupportedException`

Comment: При чем здесь вообще MySQL - это клиент или сервер? Если клиент, то начерта здесь база данных? Если сервер, то почему он лезет в сеть за данными на другой сервер? Вы точно ничего не перепутали? Если выбросить этот интрефейс, да и вообще все что с MySQL связано, то что поменяется?

Comment: У меня есть интерфейс IdataProvaider реализующий дата провайдер ,называется mysql помому что там запросы к бд

Comment: interface IDataProvider
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts();
        IEnumerable<ProductType> GetProductTypes();

    
        IEnumerable<ProductSale> GetProductSale();
        Task<ProductSale[]> GetProductSaleAsync();
    }
}

Comment: У меня задача получать  данные через php  сервер с бд и выводить их в приложение

Comment: Кстати, вы для каждого вопроса новый аккаунт зачем создаете? Почему вы не приняли мой прошлый ответ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374584/373567 Я вам не буду отвечать больше, если будете забрасывать вопросы.

Comment: @aepot И плюс вам один я там поставил. Безобразие вообще (

Comment: Извините ,просто я работаю за разными компьютерами в колледже ,знаю проще создать один аккаунт .Я читал вчерашний вопрос все получилось спасибо!

Comment: А запомнить логин-пароль эккаунта и входить всё время с него на всех компах никак?

Comment: @илья поздравляю, всё ясно, удалил ответ.